# How to create a range in a dictionairy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, range

I have following dictionairy:

```
total_working_years_dict = dict(df.TotalWorkingYears.value_counts())
total_working_years_dict
{10: 202,
 6: 125,
 8: 103,
 9: 96,
 5: 88,
 1: 81,
 7: 81,
 4: 63,
 12: 48,
 3: 42,
 15: 40,
 16: 37,
 13: 36,
 11: 36,
 21: 34,
 17: 33,
 14: 31,
 2: 31,
 20: 30,
 18: 27,
 19: 22,
 23: 22,
 22: 21,
 24: 18,
 25: 14,
 28: 14,
 26: 14,
 0: 11,
 29: 10,
 31: 9,
 32: 9,
 27: 7,
 30: 7,
 33: 7,
 36: 6,
 34: 5,
 37: 4,
 35: 3,
 40: 2,
 38: 1}
```

The keys are working years and values are numbers of employees which have such experience. I would like to transform my dictionairy so that total working yeras are given in ranges (0,6), (6,11) etc.

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: How should the ranges be determined?

Comment: Keys must be fixed values I think. But you could define "range1", "range2" as keys and use a function to map working years to ranges before you operate with the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from your dict as a Series:

```
s = pd.Series(total_working_years_dict)
```

you can use `pandas.cut` to form your groups:

```
s.index = pd.cut(s.index, bins=range(0,100,6))
```

output:

```
(6.0, 12.0]     202
(0.0, 6.0]      125
(6.0, 12.0]     103
(6.0, 12.0]      96
(0.0, 6.0]       88
...
(30.0, 36.0]      3
(36.0, 42.0]      2
(36.0, 42.0]      1
dtype: int64
```

*NB. if you now want to aggregate the counts per group, it would be more efficient to proceed to the `pandas.cut` operation **before** your initial `value_counts`. Also, I don't get the point of converting the Series to dict if you need to further process it.*

Comment: Thank You! I followed your advice to use pandas.count before counting values and it helped